# Using terraform output to update json file

Tags: terraform

I'm looking for the ability to update a JSON file from the output of Terraform. This is for the SFTP transfer service. I'm going to be creating a bucket for the SFTP service to dump to but the name of that bucket will vary.

Is there anyway to update the JSON for the IAM role responsible for writing to the SFTP S3 bucket?

Comment: This feels like an X Y problem to me. What exactly are you trying to achieve at a higher level?

Comment: I'm trying to automate the process of when a bucket is created it takes the name of that bucket and updates the JSON file of an IAM role policy. This will allow me to have a generic JSON policy regardless of the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the way to do this. Using the templatefile() function within Terraform. I'm able to pass in variables to the file.

Answer (score 0):

IAM policies are actually best defined using [`aws_iam_policy_document`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/iam_policy_document.html):

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "example" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "s3:GetObject",
    ]

    resources = [
      aws_s3_bucket.sftp.arn
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I agree but I'm confused on how to make the resources variables when I'm using aws_iam_policy_documents..

Comment: This sounds like you are not familiar with absolute basics, correct? Will update the example

Comment: Definitely wouldn't say I'm not familiar with absolute basics. I figured out what you were talking about. Thanks.